# wso2 is Custom Permission Claim Handler missing maven dependencies

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-identity-server

After attempting to retrieve permission in the access token, I came across [this solution](https://github.com/nilasini/CustomPermissionClaimHandler). However, after following the steps, I encountered an issue where I couldn't obtain the 'org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service' package. When running 'maven install', the error **'java: package org.wso2.carbon.user.core.service does not exist'** is triggered.any support to fix the error.

Comment: could you please share the entire error log printed. Also mention the used Maven version and java version